# Flutter compile error inside Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle

I had been developing a flutter mobile app for a couple of months and all was good. I just came back to the project and a few things (flutter, dart, android studio etc) upgraded. Now I can't compile my app. I created a new flutter app (the default example) and that won't compile either.

The error I'm getting is :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings remapped class cache for bq3hllkgb26p0nrblf5gh8d37 (C:\Users\Paul\.gradle\caches\5.6.2\scripts-remapped\settings_cbd968glg60byp9f5t6vvdlee\bq3hllkgb26p0nrblf5gh8d37\settings8410a2d21ed2f87c8a0398566330ee52).
> Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'D:\Apps\Flutter\Examples\flutter_app\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Paul\.gradle\caches\5.6.2\scripts\bq3hllkgb26p0nrblf5gh8d37\settings\settings8410a2d21ed2f87c8a0398566330ee52).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 57
```

I am running:
Flutter 1.20.2
Dart 2.9.1
Android Studio 4.1
Java 1.8.0_261
JVM 13.0.2
Gradle 6.7
Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up completely removing Flutter from my system and then re-installed it. This fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
flutter stable
flutter clean
flutter downgrade
cd <Your App Folder>
```

and then

```
flutter run
```

in command line

Comment: It failed on the flutter downgrade. I do have git installed.
git version 2.25.1.windows.1

Any other ideas? Thanks.

D:\Apps\Flutter\roster_me_on>flutter downgrade
Downgrade flutter to version 1.17.5
? [y|n]: y
Unable to downgrade Flutter: The tool could not update to the version 1.17.5
. This may be due to git not being installed or an internal error. Please ensure that git is installed on your computer and retry again.
Error: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
warning: unable to unlink 'dev/benchmarks/macrobenchmarks/lib/src/web/gallery/gallery_record

Comment: download git from browser

Comment: and then try the thigs in command which I have edited in my answer